# Java Runtime.exe() not returning PowerShell command output

Tags: java, windows, powershell, cmd

i try to run below command with java Runtime.exe

```
String command ="powershell (Get-item  \"D:\\test\" ).creationtime.ToString(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\")";
```

when i run it on **windows Command Prompt** it return "2017-08-07T20:03:00".

but when i run it in **myMethod** the program is also running and nothing return to me.

myMethode:

```
private static void executePowerShellCommand(String command) {

    String line = "";
    command = "cmd /c " + command;
    try {
         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
         process.getOutputStream().close();
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
         }
         reader.close();
         System.out.println("Done");
         } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

my command was wrong and the correct command is:

```
String command = "powershell (Get-item '" + filePath + "' -Force).LastAccessTime.ToString(\\\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'\\\")";
```